# How do I fetch the user ID from the shipping profile?

Tags: 8, users, commerce

I'm trying to get the User ID from Shipping Profile in Drupal Commerce using the following code, but eventually, $entity->getOwnerId() is returning me NULL in any case, if it's an authenticated user or admin it's giving me `0` as the UID.

```
function mymodule_entity_insert(EntityInterface $entity) {
    if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() === 'profile') {
        /** @var \Drupal\user\Entity\User $user */
        $user = User::load($entity->getOwnerId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shipping and billing profiles don't have a user ID, they are always anonymous because they belong to the parent entity (order/shipment), not the user.

Only address book profiles have user IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the heads-up @bojanz. Considering your response, I've found 2 possible solutions:

```
function mymodule_entity_insert(EntityInterface $entity) {
    if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() === 'profile') {
        $entity->setData('copy_to_address_book', TRUE);
        /** @var \Drupal\user\Entity\User $user */
        $user = User::load($entity->getOwnerId());
    }
}
```

More reasonable one:

```
function mymodule_entity_insert(EntityInterface $entity) {
    if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() === 'commerce_order') {
        $uid = $entity->get('uid')->target_id;
        /** @var \Drupal\user\Entity\User $user */
        $user = User::load($uid);
    }
}
```